# Best way to move from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

According to Microsoft, there is no direct migration path from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2019.  I am building out a new Windows 2019 server to host the Exchange 2019 instance.  My question is:

1) Can I migrate the mailboxes from Exchange 2010 to the new 2019 instance (ideal situation) since I'm not upgrading the existing instance

2) Or should I do an in-place upgrade of Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2016 (this is running on a 2008R2 server), then migrate the mailboxes from Exchange 2016->2019

3) Or install Exchange 2016 on the new Windows 2019 server, Migrate the mailboxes from the old Exchange 2010 -> 2016, then run an in-place upgrade from Exchange 2016->2019?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly upgrade to server 2019 from server 2010 natively. You can however use a third party app like the one from [CodeTwo](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-migrate-from-exchange-2010-directly-to-exchange-2019/)

I have done several exchange migrations and I recommend upgrading to exchange 2016 for now and waiting a few weeks to make sure everyone is happy before moving to exchange 2019.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, in-place upgrade is not possible for Exchange 2010/2013/2016, migration is the way.
https://practical365.com/exchange-server-upgrades-migrations/

As Exchange 2019 cannot coexist with Exchange 2010, I think generally it needs to be migrated to Exchange 2013/2016 first, then decommission the old 2010 server and migrate to Exchange 2019. A little complex.

If the mailbox data is not too large, pst file export and import is also a choice. 
Export the few 2010 mailboxes to pst first, then decommission the old 2010 server and deploy Exchange 2019 in a new 2019 AD environment, and finally import the pst to new Exchange 2019 mailboxes.